# Typesetting boldface math in table using siunitx and unicode-math

Tags: xetex, siunitx, unicode-math

I've been trying to get some entries in my table typeset in boldface while using siunitx for the proper alignment.

I've tried numerous other answers I found on the web, but the issue I have is that I want the numbers to be rendered in the math font, not the main font.

This is the current minimal example code for my problem:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{memoir}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{babel}  % Language hyphenation and typographical rules
\usepackage{csquotes}  % Context sensitive quotation facilities
\usepackage{microtype}  % Slightly tweak font spacing for aesthetics
\usepackage[warnings-off={mathtools-colon}]{unicode-math}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs, longtable}  % Better looking tables
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\setmainfont{EBGaramond-Regular}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[t]
    \centering
    \robustify\bfseries
    \sisetup{detect-weight, separate-uncertainty, group-minimum-digits = 4}
    \begin{tabular}
        {l S[table-format=3.2(1)] S[table-format=2.0] S[table-format=3.2(1)] S[table-format=3.0]}
        \toprule
                       & \multicolumn{2}{c}{{Point-mass}}          & \multicolumn{2}{c}{{Pendulum}} \\
                       \cmidrule(lr){2-3}                        \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
                       & {Cost $(\mu \pm \sigma)$} & {Succ.$^\dag$} & {Cost $(\mu \pm \sigma)$} & {Succ.$^\ddag$} \\
        \midrule
        {mppi}$^\S$ & {---}                   & {---}                        & 30.8 +- 12.6            & 100\unit{\percent} \\
        {disco}     & 250.8 +- 29.9           & 20\unit{\percent}            & 61.3 +- 40.0            &  70\unit{\percent} \\
        {svmpc}     & 191.7 +- 56.5           & 25\unit{\percent}            & 44.5 +- 17.9            &  70\unit{\percent} \\
        {dust}      & \bfseries 118.3 +- 7.9  & \bfseries 100\unit{\percent} & $\symbf{36.8 \pm 14.0}$ &  80\unit{\percent} \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Using `\symbf` gets the bf math font, but breaks the alignment. Could anyone please help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Not sure, but try with `\mathversion{bold}`

Comment: See if https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/680291/misalignment-with-bold-font-and-additional-symbols-in-siunitx/680305#680305
can help you.

Comment: @MadyYuvi, thanks! `\mathversion{bold}` didn't help too.

Answer (score 2):

Let me extend my comment to answer:

- Something like this?

[image]

- In real document you can remove red color, here is just for emphasis bold numbers in table.
- Table use `talltlbr` of `tabularray` package. It enables zo write table notes below table.
- In table is used `siunitx` syntax `separate-uncertainty`
- Columns are in `mode=text`

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{memoir}

\usepackage{babel}  % Language hyphenation and typographical rules
\usepackage{csquotes}  % Context sensitive quotation facilities
\usepackage{microtype}  % Slightly tweak font spacing for aesthetics
\usepackage[warnings-off={mathtools-colon}]{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{EBGaramond-Regular}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx, varwidth}
    \SetTblrStyle{note}{font=\footnotesize}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newrobustcmd\B{\DeclareFontSeriesDefault[rm]{bf}{b}%
                \bfseries\color{red}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\sisetup{table-alignment-mode = format,
         table-number-alignment = center,
         detect-weight, % <--
         mode=text,     % <--
         separate-uncertainty
        }
    \centering
\begin{talltblr}[
caption = {Reserving space in \texttt{S} columns.},
  label = {tab:S:format},
note{\S}    = {some texplanationon},
note{\dag}  = {some texplanationon},
note{\ddag} = {some texplanationon}
                ]{colspec = {l 
                            Q[c, si={table-format=3.1(3)}]
                            Q[c, si={table-format=2.0}]
                            Q[c, si={table-format=2.1(3)}]
                            Q[c, si={table-format=3.0{\,\%}}]
                            },
                 cell{3-Z}{5} = {appto= {\,\%} },
                 row{1,2} = {guard}
                 }
    \toprule
        &   \SetCell[c=2]{c}    Point - mass
            &  &   \SetCell[c=2]{c}    Pendulum
                     &                  \\
        \cmidrule[lr]{2-3}
        \cmidrule[l]{4-5}
        &   Cost $(\mu \pm \sigma)$
            &   Succ.\TblrNote{\dag}
                &   Cost $(\mu \pm \sigma)$
                    &   Succ.\TblrNote{\ddag}   \\
    \midrule
mppi\TblrNote{\S}
        & {{{--}}}  
            & {{{--}}}  
                & 30.8(12.6)  
                    & 100           \\
disco   & 250.8(29.9)
            & 20
                & 61.3(40.0)
                    &  70           \\
svmpc   & 191.7(56.5)
            & 25
                & 44.5(17.9)
                    &  70           \\
dust    &\B 118.3(1)%(7.9)
            &\B 100
                &\B 36.8
                    &    80         \\
    \bottomrule
\end{talltblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Fantastic, is it possible to meet the output by using `dcolumn.sty`, just a curiosity, I'm asking

Comment: @MadyYuvi, I never tried but I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: @Zarko, thanks for the reply, specially the addition of the table notes. But it is still not quite right. If you notice, the numbers are all being typeset on the main font (Garamond) and I'm trying to get them to use the maths font (STIX Two). The difference is more visible if you use \setmainfont{EBGaramond-Regular}[Numbers={OldStyle}]. If I remove `mode=text` from the `\sisetup` call, the font is correct, but `\B` doesn't change the font weight just the colour.

Comment: @MadyYuvi, `mode` text is essential to have equal width of boldface and nobold faves fonts,, as you discover. Sory, but I'm not experts fo fonts eidher :-(